# When to free node in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, free

When I'm inputting data in `curr->data` I first allocate memory by doing `curr = (NODE*) malloc (sizeof(NODE));`. Then I build list and eventually at the end, print it. Somewhere in the program I have to free the memory that I've used, but I don't know when to do it. After building the list, or after I print the list? or can I do this?

```
printf("How many elements do you want to make? ");
scanf("%d", &NumElem);
head = NULL;
for (i = 0; i < NumElem; i++)
{
    //memory allocate
    curr = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    printf("Number %d: ", i+1);
    scanf("%d", &curr->num);
    FLUSH;

    if (head == NULL)/*beginning of the list*/
    {
        curr->next = head;
        head = curr;
        *tail = curr;
    }
    else /*adding on the list*/
    {
        curr->next = head;
        head = curr;
    }
    free (curr);
}//for
```

Can I free each time after I put data inside the current node?

Comment: When you're *done* using it. In this case you're not done using it - even if you're done for the loop. If you `free` it then `tail` and `head` (e.g.) now points to junk as the object ha been `free`d.

Comment: You cannot reference memory again once you have freed it, as the contents will be undefined. After you have done what you need to with the list (printing it I suppose), then traverse the list, freeing each node along the way.

Comment: Quite important: What is `FLUSH;`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose you're reserved a local meeting room where you plan to have a meeting and then a party. When would you release your reservation ... immediately after you reserved it, after you've had the meeting but before you've had the party, or after you've had both the meeting and the party?

`malloc` and `free` are like that ... `malloc` reserves an area of memory for your use and `free` cancels the reservation. If you continue to use the memory after you've cancelled the reservation, the behavior is undefined.

In your case, you need to free your entire list of nodes. You can do that in a loop, but there's a common trap: freeing a node before accessing its `next` pointer. The danger is that this almost always works in practice, but it's undefined and sometimes it won't work ... possibly in some software controlling life-critical machinery. Best to learn to do it right now:

```
void free_list(NODE* list)
{
    while (list)
    {
        NODE* next = list->next;
        free(list);
        list = next;
    }
}
```

Or in a slightly more compact form,

```
void free_list(NODE* list)
{
    for (NODE* next; list; list = next)
    {
        next = list->next;
        free(list);
    }
}
```

If your node contain pointers to strings or other objects that were `malloc`ed and need to be freed, those free calls would be done in free_list before freeing the node itself.